# applying class selector to many h2 elements

Tags: css

I want to apply .special class selector to a three h2 elements.

```
.special {
    font-style: italic;
} 

<h2 class="special">Help Please</h2>

<h2>Can we apply from one CSS rule to many h2 elements?</h2>

<h2>You help will be appreciated</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply add the class attribute to all three

```
.special {
    font-style: italic;
} 

<h2 class="special">Help Please</h2>

<h2 class="special">Can we apply from one CSS rule to many h2 elements?</h2>

<h2 class="special">You help will be appreciated</h2>
```

Alternatively, to select the first three `h2` elements within a parent, use:

```
h2:nth-of-type(-n+3){
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Or, to style all `h2` elements, use:

```
h2{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. is there any other simple way to do it? I don't want to populated the document with the three classes. It's repetitive.

Comment: @edquijano - see the second option in the answer. Alternatively, if all `h2` require the styling, you dont need to use classes at all, in your CSS simply use `h2{}`, alternatively you need to add the class to each element to get the style

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/692u47Lo/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="special">
     <h2>Help Please</h2>    
     <h2>Can we apply from one CSS rule to many h2 elements?</h2>
     <h2>You help will be appreciated</h2> 
</div>
<hr/>
 <h2>Help Please normal h2</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.special h2 {
    font-style: italic;
}
```